# Two links on the same line in this body div?

Tags: html, css, text, hyperlink

I have the following div

```
#body {
    line-height:1.5em;
    width:700px;  
    margin:auto; 
    overflow-x: hidden; 
    padding:12.5px;
    color:#4e443c;
    font-size:16px;
    font-family:"Courier";
    display:table;
}
```

In the body text I have multiple links and some of them work some of them don't. After a quick search I've found that `display:inline-block` would solve this issue; however, my div would no longer be centered on the page. Another quick google search brought me to try `display:inline-block` combined with `text-align:center`, but this also caused issues because the text in the div is now centered, and not left.

Is there any way to do this with a centered div with the text aligned left?

My HTML is just a simple div with text.

```
<div id="body">
      Text here. <a href="http://google.com">Example link</a>. <a href="http://google.com">Another</a> example.
</div>
```

Comment: Show us your HTML Markup

Comment: @LuisP.A. Updated question.

Comment: You mean something like this - http://jsfiddle.net/MrMarlow/bqew7L09/1/?

Comment: @MrMarlow Yes, similar to that.

Comment: Ah, left alignment - http://jsfiddle.net/MrMarlow/bqew7L09/3/ - what else needs changing?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by using margins for placement, then using tags around all internal elements (a for links, span for non-href).

Example below;

**html**

```
<div id="body">
    <a href="#">Link</a>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
    <span>Link</span>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
</div>
```

**css**

```
#body {
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 400px;
    border: solid 1px red;
}
#body a, #body span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 1.7em;
}
```

**example**

http://jsfiddle.net/MrMarlow/bqew7L09/3/

Comment: So, for every link I would have to close the `<span>` and open a new one after it?

Comment: That will be a pain to add to my entire site. Any thoughts on how to reconfigure all my `body` divs with a script or anything?

Comment: Well, in theory, that depends on if you ever have 2 non-href lines in a row. If not, you could bypass them and just play with the line-height on `a tags`, since they will be 100% width, meaning the static text will be forced between them

Comment: For example - 1 single non-link line between link lines - http://jsfiddle.net/MrMarlow/bqew7L09/4/

Comment: And 2 link lines, as there is no separator anchor, will end up "broken" like this - http://jsfiddle.net/MrMarlow/bqew7L09/5/